# Amazon S3 bucket policy to for federated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I am trying to give a federated user ( ADFS + SAML + STS ) access to an Amazon S3 bucket . I am trying to give the principal as

```
  "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:sts: accountid:federated-user/someuser"
                ]
             }
```

and

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
```

But I cant seem to get the right access . Any pointers on this

Comment: a space in `arn` or just typo?

Comment: @BMW I think I might have done it to avoid rendering an emoji .

Answer (score 3):

Does the user assume a specific role first before attempting to access the bucket?

If so, try including both the user and the assumed role in your bucket policy, ie

```
"AWS": [
  "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/User/joe@example.com",
  "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/User"
]
```

Where `User` is the role name.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old post, but the above answer of @alkalinecoffee did help me figure out the best answer for today

IAM role policies now use Conditions a lot:

```
{
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::<s3bucket>",
     "arn:aws:s3:::<s3bucket>/*"
  ],
  Condition = {
    ArnNotEquals = {
      aws:PrincipalArn = [
        "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/<region>/<rolename>",
        "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:assumed-role/<rolename>/<federateduser>"
      ]
   }
}
```

This will block ALL Users except for the federateduser defined in the `ArnNotEquals` condition.

Comment: "Action": "s3:* is dangerous
I lost access to a bucket 
try to test with "Action": "s3:DeleteObject" which is less harsh

Comment: This is just a mere example, you can trim down less action as needed